# Path variable for default browser in Windows

Tags: windows, browser, path

Some files or folders in Windows have path variables (like %appdata%, %systemroot%, %userprofile%, etc). Is there anything similar to get the default browser?

For example, it could take the value `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` if Google Chrome is the default browser, `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` if Firefox is the default browser, `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` if Internet Explorer is the default browser, etc and always have the same name no matter what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
reg QUERY HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command /ve
```

And you will get something like:

```
(Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Then you can easily parse it.

Comment: How do I use this in for example the Run dialog?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Just enter a URL in the "Run" box and it will open in your default browser, for example type `http://www.google.com` following by <enter>

Comment: The value of this registry key is `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1` but my default browser is Chrome.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This returns Internet Explorer no matter what the default browser is. To get the default browser, I've figured out that you need to go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice\ProgId`, and then use that value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[value here]\shell\open\command`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Could you please make this into an answer?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=3" %a in ('reg QUERY HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice /v ProgId') do reg QUERY HKCR\%a\shell\open\command`    came done to that one-line. I will look to parse exactly the executable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the info about the default browser, you need to check the Windows registry.

You can find more info about this here :

https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/

Also you might won to check this to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222367/windows-registry-key-for-check-whether-ie-is-the-default-browser